# I am trying to make a responsive rectangle with an image to the left inside and text centered

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to make a responsive tweet `button` with the twitter bird `float`ed left, the text next to it and centered.

My code is:

```css
.flex-rectangle {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 7px solid #00A5EF;
}
/* Styles Twitter Bird png */

.image-wrapper {
  padding-top: 10%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}
img .tweet {
  float: left;
}
/* Tweet This: */

.span-content {
  display: block;
  color: #00A5EF;
}
.span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #00A5EF;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-rectangle">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/281152/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg" class="tweet" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
  <div class="span-content">
    <span>Tweet This</span>
  </div>
</div>

CSS
```

I've tried pretty much everything under the sun.

I can't seem to get the rectangle to shrink and widen when I resize the page or go into Dev Tools and use the mobile device pane.

I understand CSS less than I do JavaScript at this point. Not sure if I should use `flexbox` in this instance or how I would do that.

Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/twhite96/pen/aZmrXO?editors=1100)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `quotes` using pseudo element `::before` and a`::after`

> Thank you. This works for the most part. However I can't get the
>   twitter bird to float left and the text to be beside it. Any
>   suggestions?

I used `flexbox` the text will be next to the twitter button on desktop view, and below on mobile view.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Satisfy);

/*Styles for whole page */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 7px solid #00a5ef;
}
#page-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center
}
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #1485C7;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
/* On: */

h1 .center {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: "Satisfy";
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #1485C7;
}
h1 .bigger {
  font-size: 46px;
  color: #1485C7;
  display: block
}
/* Rectangle 1: */

.flex-rectangle {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  flex: 1 15%;
  margin: 0 15%;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D";
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
}
.flex-rectangle::before {
  color: #00a5ef;
  content: open-quote;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 25vw;
  left: -15vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
.flex-rectangle::after {
  color: #00a5ef;
  content: close-quote;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 25vw;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15vw;
  top: 50%;
}
.text {
  align-self: flex-end
}
.span-content {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #00A5EF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #00A5EF;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div class="flex-rectangle">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Random Quotes<span class="center">On</span><span class="bigger">Design</span></h1>
    </div>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/281152/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg" class="tweet" />
    <div id="buttons">
      <div class="span-content">
        Tweet This
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Random Quotes</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for the most part. However I can't get the twitter bird to float left and the text to be beside it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @twhite96 see updated answer, the text will be next to the  twitter button on desktop view, and below on mobile view

Comment: This almost works. But it still isn't quite working the way I'd like. I have a mockup. Maybe that will help you, help me. You can find the direct link to it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d96f6h9ogui1iqe/Rando%20Quote_3.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: so the text  is on top, and you have still another quote which wasn't in the code.

Answer (score 1):

you have to place the bird and the text to one `div` and code for the image element in order to code for the image part you have to call first the first parent div and other div in one code where the image element is located `.flex-rectangle .image-wrapper img`to edit the code for image. and also you have to insert the html code for `<span>Tweet This</span>` inside the `.image-wrapper` to make the image go left and your text go center.

CSS CODE :

```
.flex-rectangle {
       float: left;
       margin: 0 5px;
       max-width: 500px;
       text-align:center;
       width: 200%;
       background: #FFFFFF;
       border: 7px solid #00A5EF;
    }

/* Styles Twitter Bird png */

.image-wrapper {
                 padding-top: 10%;
                position: relative;
                margin: auto;
                max-width: 125;
                max-height: 50px;
                width: 100%;
                padding-bottom: 15%;
}


.flex-rectangle .image-wrapper img {
                float: left;
                max-width: 50px;
                max-height: 50px;
                width: 100%;

            }
/* Tweet This: */
.span-content {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                color: #00A5EF;
            }


            .span {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: OpenSans;
                font-size: 36px;
                color: #00A5EF;
            }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="flex-rectangle">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/281152/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg" class="tweet"/>
        <div id="buttons">
            <div class="span-content">
                <span>Tweet This</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```